# What is the "keep alive taking too long to send" error indicating?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport, airplay

Since yesterday I am encountering WiFi drop outs with my Airport Express.
I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 and have a 1<sup>st</sup> generation A1264 Airport Express.

The drop outs are mainly noticeable as the music over Airplay is interrupted.
In the console I see the following error that repeats itself every drop out:

```
13/11/16 3:01:51.527 PM coreaudiod[274]: 2016-11-13 03:01:51.527435 PM [AirPlay] ### Keep alive taking too long to send (5 seconds)
13/11/16 3:01:55.136 PM coreaudiod[274]: 2016-11-13 03:01:55.135959 PM [AirPlay] *** Sent futile retransmit to 10.0.1.1:6001 for seq 31771, latest 32840 (1 total)
13/11/16 3:01:55.138 PM coreaudiod[274]: 2016-11-13 03:01:55.137672 PM [AirPlay] *** Sent futile retransmit to 10.0.1.1:6001 for seq 31772, latest 32840 (2 total)
13/11/16 3:01:55.138 PM coreaudiod[274]: 2016-11-13 03:01:55.138033 PM [AirPlay] *** Sent futile retransmit to 10.0.1.1:6001 for seq 31773, latest 32840 (3 total)
```

I have restarted my laptop and my Airport Express, but the errors keep appearing.

When I monitor the throughput of my WiFi signal I see the following (screenshot shows 2 drop outs):
[image]

What might be causing this issue? And how can I diagnose this further?

Comment: Did you move the APX to another location? Is the APX near any new microwave ovens? Usually APXs are used to distribute internet connections, too. If the APX is connected to your ISP's router/modem, have you rebooted this device, too?

Comment: Did not move the APX.  A microwave oven is 5m away, but this has been the case  the past 2 years without issue. I have no ISP modem, just an ethernet cable coming out of the wall.

Comment: "...just an ethernet cable coming out of the wall." This ethernet cable _must_ lead to a device which connects the APX to the internet. If you don't own/control this device, it behooves you to figure out how to find out how to get it rebooted.

Comment: The cable goes into an ethernet port in the wall, which is connected to a central switch in the apartment building. I cannot get it rebooted just for my issue. Shouldn't be necessary either as my primary problem is not with internet access (plugging in the ethernet cable directly works fine), but with Airplay dropping out every few seconds. Hence, it seems to be something with my own network. Any suggestions there?

Comment: The issue is back again :( Does anybody have any other suggestions except for rebooting the switch of the whole building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have "solved" the issue by factory resetting my Airport Express.
This does seem a bit of a sledgehammer approach, so everyone is still welcome to post a real solution.